# jquery chosen multilevel hierarchy

Tags: jquery-chosen

I am using jquery chosen plugin. http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/
In jquery chosen it is possible to display dropdown like

- --select--
- **main manu1**

  - menu1
  - menu2
- **main manu2**

  - menu3
  - menu4

but i want to display dropdown like

- --select--
- **main menu1**

  - **submanu1**

    - menu1
    - menu2
- **main menu2**

  - **submanu2**

    - menu1
    - menu2

is it possible? please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the whitespaces (&nbsp) from the labels of the selection you can modify jq-Chosen to trim them.

Replace `item.html` by `item.html.replace( /&nbsp;/g,'' )` in the function ***choice_label*** starting on line 173 (Chosen 1.4.2):

```
AbstractChosen.prototype.choice_label = function(item) {

  if (this.include_group_label_in_selected && (item.group_label != null)) {
    return "<b class='group-name'>" + item.group_label + "</b>" + item.html.replace( /&nbsp;/g,'' );
  } else {
    return item.html.replace( /&nbsp;/g,'' );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's not unless you hack it somehow. I needed this myself recently but concluded there was no support. There is nothing on their [page of examples](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/%20their%20page%20of%20examples) suggesting that it would be possible, and the paragraph

> Because chosen replaces normal html select fields, you don't need to do anything special to make it work for browsers without JavaScript. You don't need to do anything special on the back end to handle the data either -- the form field still gets submitted as normal.

seems to suggest that Chosen only enhances the user experience of native select boxes and doesn't really add any complexity to them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible but I am still in some kind of struggle.

```
            <?php
            $args = array(
                'type'          => 'post',
                'orderby'       => 'term_group',
                'hide_empty'    => 0,
                'hierarchical'  => 0,
                'parent'        => 0,
                'exclude_tree'  => '49,1,63'
            );
            $topcats = get_categories( $args );
            ?>

            <select class="chosen-select" multiple>
                <?php
                    foreach ($topcats as $a) {
                        echo "<optgroup label='$a->name'>";
                        $args = array(
                            'child_of'       => $a->cat_ID,
                            'hide_empty'   => false
                        );
                        $children = get_terms('category', $args);
                        foreach ($children as $child) {
                            $cat = get_category($child->term_id);
                            $lvl = get_level($cat);
                            $space = "";
                            for ($i = 1; $i < $lvl; $i++) { $space .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;"; }
                            echo "<option>$space $child->name</option>";
                        }
                        echo "</optgouop>";
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
```

I am working in Wordpress so I loaded categories and by using a get level hack I found on the internet (I am truly sorry but can not remember where, so mr. author, please forgive me)

Here is the hack:

```
function get_level($category, $level = 0)
{
    if ($category->category_parent == 0) {
        return $level;
    } else {
        $level++;
        $category = get_category($category->category_parent);
        return get_level($category, $level);
    }
}
```

The real problem which I stil have not been able to figure out is how to delete those spaces from single selects. If you use this code and select one option, the spaces will transfer into the selection line of multiple chosen select box.